# Setting a razor variable to the value of a dropdown

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, razor

I have a form inside of a modal that takes in a list of my total ec2 instances. I am trying to adjust the second drop down to the value of the first one so the second drop down sees the instances relative volumes.

```
<form action="/S3/AttachVolume/" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <p>Please double check the ids of your instance and volume</p>
             <label for="instanceId">InstanceId:</label>
             <select class="form-control text-center" name="instanceId" id="instances" style="margin: 0 auto">
             @for (var i = 0; i <= totalcount - 1; i++)
             {
                 foreach (var instances in Model.instances.Reservations[i].Instances)
                 {
                     <option>@instances.InstanceId</option>
                 }
             }
             </select>
             <label for="type">Volume Id:</label>
             <select class="form-control text-center" name="volumeId" id="volumeId" style="margin: 0 auto">
             @foreach (var volume in @*aboveinstance*@.BlockDeviceMappings)
             {
                 <option>@volume.DeviceName</option>
             }
         </select>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" style="width: 100%;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Detach</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Is it possible to store the value of the instanceId`<select>` inside of a variable similar to var so I can loopthrough it in the second select?

for reference the `var instance` contains the following data [image]

Sorry if this is obvious I am new to .net and razor and its hard to find resources when working with the aws sdk

Comment: Use selecting an option in first dropdown happens in client side, you should use ajax to get the data for second dropdwown based on the selection from first dropdown. Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577597/how-to-update-dropdownlistfor-selectlist-with-jquery)

Comment: What you want is cascading dropdownlists. Refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Razor renders the View on the server side and doesn't know about any client-side change that the user can make.

Any even that occurs *after* the page is loaded, such as a Select change, must be handled though javascript, better if using a framework like AngularJs that will make your life much easier.

Your Javascript function will call a service every time the Select value changes to get the data it's needed to re-populate the other Control.