# Multi Level @Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a tree with height of 4 in my database [Id] [Name] [Level] [Parent].  I would like to have 4 @Html.DropDownListFor. One for each level of the tree. 
So far I have this: `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Selections.L1, new SelectList(Model.L1s, "Id", "Name"), "Please Select", new { data_bind="optionsValue:'L1';" })` where L1 selection for the top level and L1s are the options.

I would like to make a call to my controller and send the selected L1 and return the L2s to pick from for the second select but I am unsure how to do so.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577597/how-to-update-a-second-dropdown-based-on-the-selection-of-first-dropdown-selecti

Comment: Refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) for an example of cascading fropdownlists